# Timeout calling PRIVATE API Gateway from another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call my private API gateway from a lambda function in another AWS account. But i am getting timeout while making the call (Actually the http call is just stuck and hits my client side timeout).

In the AWS account which hosts the private AWS account i did the following
 * Created my private API gateway and lambda behind the API

- Create resource policy and provided access to the VPC endpoint of the other AWS caller (caller)
- create VPC endpoint with private DNS enabled.
- Attached policy to VPC endpoint with full access, security group with access to all traffic.

In the second AWS account (caller) i did the following
 * Create VPC and VPC endpoint for API gateway with full access.

- created lambda in the VPC with security group with access to all traffic (inbound and outbound)
- In lambda I am using the public DNS of the VPC endpoint(Account 1) and used header 'x-apigw-api-id'

I already tried the debugging steps mentioned in this page https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-private-endpoint-connection/. 
Also tried whitelisting based on the VPC ID instead of VPC endpoint ID.

Any suggestions for resolving this issue.

Comment: Hi. So you have 2 accounts and 2 vpcs (one in each account). Based on your description I don't see any cross-account peering connection between the 2 VPCs. Do you have such a connection?

Comment: @Marcin No, i don't have a VPC peering connection. Is that required for this ?
In the AWS doc https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-private-endpoint-connection/
it say we need peering connection only if the API are in different regions

Comment: You are right. If its the same account, a peering connection is not required.

Comment: Does Lambda in the caller account have [proper execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-permissions) for vpc access?

Comment: I've just recreated the two account setup with the private API gateway and lambda in private subnet of a second account. Haven't encountered any strange issues. The only thing was that I forgot to re-deploy my stage after I modified my policy on api gateway as I removed the second statement from the [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html#apigateway-resource-policies-source-vpc-example) to all access from any vpc.

Comment: wow, thanks for trying out. I justed figured out the issue. I was using the VPC endpoint of the other account while making a call. That fixed the issue

Comment: No problem. Glad it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the isssue. I was using the VPC endpoint of the other aws account while making a call. When i used the VPC endpoint of the same account it worked.