# Calling private API Gateway from a public API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to call a private API Gateway (B) endpoint from a public one (A), but I'm getting timeout errors when performing the call.

I've read https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-private-cross-account-vpce/ and [Timeout calling PRIVATE API Gateway from another AWS account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133268/timeout-calling-private-api-gateway-from-another-aws-account), which look similar to my goal, but I'm probably missing something.

The APIs A and B are in different accounts and belong to different VPCs. The VPCs have private DNS option enabled, and the same security group which allows inbound traffic for all protocols and all port ranges.

[image]

The API B defines a policy to allow traffic from A's VPCE, as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "execute-api:/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-A"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "execute-api:/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following calls from A give a timeout:

- curl -i https://public-DNS-VPCE-A/stage-name-B/endpoint -H "Host: https://B-Invoke-Url"
- curl -i https://public-DNS-VPCE-A/stage-name-B/endpoint -H "x-apigw-api-id: B-id"
- curl -i https://public-DNS-VPCE-B/stage-name-B/endpoint -H "Host: https://B-Invoke-Url"
- curl -i https://public-DNS-VPCE-B/stage-name-B/endpoint -H "x-apigw-api-id: B-id"
- curl -i https://B-Invoke-Url/endpoint

Any suggestions for resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same request as you, but i think aws is not allow to do that

the private api gateway require a vpc endpoint, which mean you can only access within the same VPC

so the stupid way is

Public apigw -> vpc link -> internal nlb -> ec2 -> nginx -> vpc endpoint ->private apigw

but if we doing like that, what is the point to have a private apigw